# How to use for inside IntelliJ Live Template?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I am trying to write a simple Groovy script which concatenates strings.
This Groovy script is intended to be used as a variable inside an IntelliJ Live Template and generate some code.

When I set the **$variableResolvedWithGroovyScript$** to have the following value:

```
groovyScript("def elements=[\"firstElem\",\"secondElem\",\"thirdElem\"];  
          String result=\"\";  
          for (String element : elements) {      
              result=result+element;        
          }        
          return result;"
, clipboard())
```

I get below error:

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'return' @ line 1, column 183.
   lt+element;         }         return res
                             ^

1 error
```

However, if I try and remove the for braces(***{*** and ***}***) it works without any problems:

```
groovyScript("def elements=[\"firstElem\",\"secondElem\",\"thirdElem\"];  
          String result=\"\";  
          for (String element : elements)      
              result=result+element;
          return result;"
, clipboard())
```

If I take above script and run it inside a Groovy Console it works without problems, so I assume this is a Live Template issue. 
I tried to escape the braces in the same way the quotation marks are escaped, but without any luck.

How can I write a for(containing more than one instruction) inside of a Live Template ?

Comment: Also reported bug on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work by loading the Groovy script from the disk. So instead of the **$variableResolvedWithGroovyScript$**'s value, which was:

```
groovyScript("def elements=[\"firstElem\",\"secondElem\",\"thirdElem\"];  
      String result=\"\";  
      for (String element : elements) {      
          result=result+element;        
      }        
      return result;"
, clipboard())
```

I simply used:

```
groovyScript("d:\\Some\\Path\\Concatenate.groovy" , clipboard())
```

The d:\Some\Path\Concatenate.groovy worked with braces and I was also able to define new methods and so on.